# Getting different number result from SOQL and report

Tags: soql, reporting

I run both the SOQL query and report to get the number of parties without order and hearing. In SOQL query, I run in developer console:

```
Select count(Id) From Ida_Party__c 
Where Case__c = null and hearing__c = null
and createdDate < 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```

The count returned is 218792.

In report, I pretty much run the same thing: 
[image]

I have checked the fields and API names do match. But the report only returned 14097 records.

The gap is huge here.

So what might be the cause of this huge gap?

Comment: May be "User Context" of report and "System Context" for Developer Console.

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with this sobject, but it is not exactly the same. In the query you search for Case__c = null, in the report Order Number equal ""

Comment: @LironC It is just api name vs display name

Comment: Unless you're in GMT, the createddate filters are also different, by the number of hours between you and GMT. That's probably not going to explain all the difference, but that may be part of it.

Comment: @user36778 the Query Editor doesn't run in System Context.

Comment: @LanceShi Have you tried 'Select Count_Distinct(id)' to see if you get the same?

Comment: Is the report type just Ida_Party__c? If it's Ida_Party__c and some child object, the report type can restrict it to just lines with some child records.